# Get specific element in site path in twig template

Tags: theming

```
The current page url is http://website/p1/p2/p3/p4
In Drupal 8 twig, use function to get path p1/p2/p3/p4
{{ set site_path = path("<current>") }}
{{ site_path }}
The site_path is p1/p2/p3/p4
How to get the element in the path, for example, the second p2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/split.html) filter splits a string by the given delimiter and returns a list of strings:

```
{% set site_path = path('<current>') %}
{% set exppath = site_path|split('/') %}
{{ exppath.2 }}
```

another way to array element: `{{ exppath[2] }}`

Comment: Please, preprocess this instead.